# Can't make jQuery UI element draggable?

Tags: jquery, scroll, draggable

I am having trouble with the draggable feature. Please see the page at the link below. Scroll in the window and look what the "draggable" element does. The move area is the border of the window.

http://in-wien.com/test/draggable/bug.htm

Thanks,
Philipp

Comment: I see no problem with your page, can you try to be more clear about what the problem is?

Comment: @philipp-caha Your CSS might be causing the problem. Please check your CSS that any margin values is given to your dragged element..

Comment: +1 @Brad I see the problem. To find out: Click with mouse scroll bar and drag it to bottom. In that certain point window frame snaps to  cursor.

Comment: I use Windows7 Google Chrom, Firefox and IE9 and the same Problem with each Browser. When scroll finished (mouse up) the window sticks to the mouse pointer.

Comment: Problem fixed :-)

The optional Parameter "cancel" can stop it.

    $('#testdiv').draggable(
    {
            stack: "#dragset div.uix",
            cursor: 'move',
            opacity: 0.5,
            handle: '.outbox',
            cancel: '.contentbox'
    });

Comment: Would you post that as an answer?

Comment: Can you please add the solution as an answer?  You can then select yours as the correct answer and close out your question. It may seem strange, but it is the preferred way of dealing with situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

The optional Parameter "cancel" can stop it.

```
$('#testdiv').draggable( { stack: "#dragset div.uix", cursor: 'move', opacity: 0.5, handle: '.outbox', cancel: '.contentbox' });
```

:)